# Multiple Subforms in Symfony2 mapped to existing data

Tags: symfony

I'm creating a monthly invoice module for my Symfony2 project. I'm attempting to provide the user with a single form that lists all employees for the current invoice period with two input fields per employee. Similar to a spreadsheet, each row has the Employee name and then a field to input their individual hourly rate and their total hours of work for the month.

Here's the entity defintions (only posting relevant fields for sake of brevity)

```
class EmployeeRecords
    $id (auto-increment)
    $name_first
    $name_last

class Invoice
    $id (auto-increment)
    $invoice_date (datetime)
    $attendance (Doctrine mapped to InvoiceAttendance)

class InvoiceAttendance
    $id (auto-increment)
    $invoice_fk (Doctrine mapped to Invoice)
    $employee_fk (Doctrine mapped to EmployeeRecords)
    $hours
    $hourly_rate
```

I've created a FormAttendance form type for the InvoiceAttendance entity

```
$builder->add('hours', 'number', array('precision' => 4));
$builder->add('hourly_rate', 'money', array('currency' => 'USD', 'precision' => 4));
...
$resolver->setDefaults(
    array(
        'data_class' => 'Entity\InvoiceAttendance'));
```

I've considered building a FormInvoiceAttendance class to act as the "superform" that holds the collection of FormAttendance subforms for each employee. But all that would do is create one "blank" instance of the employee attendance form and it wouldn't associate the values with any existing employee.

```
$builder->add('attendance', 'collection', array('type' => new FormAttendance()));
```

---

In theory, the entire process is as follows:

1) User creates a new Invoice in the system, assigning a date to the invoice (along with other general information).

2) Once created, user can go to the form to input the attendance for the employees for the invoice period (this is the "spreadsheet" type form).

3) Each row of the spreadsheet form is essentially the FormAttendance type and should be mapped to the corresponding employee.

4) User submits the form and various calculations are performed. Ultimately, the collection of InvoiceAttendance values are persisted to the InvoiceAttendance table in the database and the total values are updated for the Invoice table in the database.

---

I've used "collection" form types before to dynamically add subforms to a form collection but I seem to be stumbling over the idea when the "source" of data for the "collection" is pre-existing.

I've explored a couple of possible solutions... but none seem to get me past the basic hurdle of embedding a subform multiple times within a single form.

Answer (score 0):

After a good night's sleep... this challenge is really nothing more than using the collection form type. I totally forgot you could access the domain object linked to the form type from within twig.

**InvoicesController**

```
$roster // ArrayCollection of EmployeeRecord domain objects

foreach($roster as $employee) {
    $attendance = new InvoiceAttendance();
    $attendance->setEmployeeFk($employee);
    $invoice->getAttendance()->add($attendance);
}
```

**attendance.html.twig**

```
{% for employee in form.attendance %}
    {{ employee.vars.value.employeeFk.nameFirst }} {{ employee.vars.value.employeeFk.nameLast }}
    {{ form_widget(employee.hourlyRate) }}
    {{ form_widget(employee.hours) }}
{% endfor %}
```